# having public computers without joining the domain

Tags: wireless-networking

Good Morning,

I would like to know what is the best arrangement for setting up 24 computers at a facility. We do not want these computers to join our domain because of security concerns. We plan on having these public computers connect to our wifi network. If anyone knows of the best way to approach this, that would be great! We also need to add printers to these public computers. We would also like to lock each computer down. Since we are not connecting by network, I assume we would have to configure each group policy.

Comment: I am curious: Why would putting them into the domain create a security risk? I fail do see how it does that.

Answer (score 1):

Where I work we just leave them in their default work groups when we don't want them on the domain, then you can delegate network resources (such as printers, shared drives, whatever else you might have) manually.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure a guest network in your wifi router (I don't know whether your router supports guest network facility or not.) and connect those computers to that network. Not only computers you can add printer's or any other devices to this network. Based on your wifi router check for other options. If your's is cisco router then give a try downloading "cisco connect" software.

Below is the link to configure guest network in cisco router

http://www6.nohold.net/Cisco2/GetArticle.aspx?docid=c3e42afc03994df5bb6bc531b42e9201_21461.xml&pid=8&converted=0